# ID a story with someone (a woman I think) taken hostage by an AI

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to ID a 70s science fiction movie involving an AI that takes a woman (I think) hostage. It's not *Demon Seed*. IIRC it takes place in some slightly futuristic (in a 70s way) accommodation in a hi-tech looking establishment rather than in an automated home like *Demon Seed*. Another element that differs from *Demon Seed* is that the husband (I think) of the hostage asks for conjugal rights on the grounds that humans need these to remain healthy. This allows them to plot an escape together.

Comment: I believe this is Colossus, the Corbin Project.

Comment: @NomadMaker Agreed, Colossus. You should post an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much @NomadMaker ! I'd forgotten that movie had a hostage subplot. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanPiponi Hopefully somebody else remembers the movie better; I just remember that subplot, with the computer's camera turning itself off (well, the red light on the camera went off, but I don't think the camera does). I don't remember much else. I remember that I read the book and the sequel as well as seeing the movie. But the details are from a long time ago.

Comment: Oh! It seems there's a trilogy of books. I'll have to read them.

Comment: I think the first book in the series, was the best, the others started getting a little bit wilder and unbelievable to me, when I read them 30-40 years ago.

Comment: Here's a funny coincidence: I frequently go for a run right by the "hi-tech looking establishment" I mentioned. Some of the exteriors were filmed at the Lawrence Hall of Science in Berkeley, but I didn't recognise it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Colossus: The Forbin Project (1970)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064177/)

Doctor Forbin was the name of the primary creator of the giant computer Colossus.  Doctor Cleo Markham was another scientist on the project, maybe his second-in-command.  After Colossus takes over, Markham acts as Forbin's mistress.  I don't recall whether it was an act, or whether they were actually romantically involved (they may have been married between the first book and the sequel).

Forbin, who was under constant surveillance, had convinced Colossus that some privacy was necessary for human beings, so it turns the cameras off while she visits, allowing them to plot against it.  I don't think escape was their goal; they were trying to shut down Colossus.

Comment: It was an act at first. And Colossus turns the cameras off only when they retire to the bedroom together, so they must do quite a lot of acting.