# Identification of a black and white sci-fi film where the US and USSR build supercomputers to run missiles

Tags: story-identification, movie

Black and white sci-fi film. US and USSR build supercomputers to run missiles, computers link up become sentient and take over the world by threat of nukes. A designer tries to disable them, fails and is made to watch his friends executed as he is needed.

Comment: This is, of course, the Forbin Project; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241689/id-a-story-with-someone-a-woman-i-think-taken-hostage-by-an-ai/241698#241698. Not black and white, I might add, but filmed in Technicolor

Comment: Thankyou, i work in analogue mentally so B&W could have been the TV.

Comment: Found it free to download on internet archive, Happy Happy Joy Joy!

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (or confirm it's correct in a comment)

Answer (score 33):

This is *[Colossus: The Forbin Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus:_The_Forbin_Project)*.

> [A]n advanced American defense system, named Colossus, becom[es] sentient. After being handed full control, Colossus' draconian logic expands on its original nuclear defense directives to assume total control of the world and end all warfare for the good of mankind despite its creators' orders to stop.

Comment: Its star, from a movie well over fifty years old, is still working. i recall the portrayal of the computers while of course dated is not a cringey as many movies that dealt with artificial intelligence made in those days -- it had the two machines communicating in a language they made up and i believe something like that was alleged to have occurred in real life within the past decade or so.

Comment: @releseabe - It struck me that Hollywood would have given it a stupid action sequence ending if it was filmed today.

Comment: yes, it was, thinking back, the sort of low-key way the showed the power of the machine. Colossus did not use robots/cyborgs or anything -- SPOILER: its great willingness to, in concert with Guardian, use nukes and its invulnerable location made humans obey it. It seemed fairly plausible. But we won't know until we turn over control of our nukes to the equivalent of AlphaZero (the superhuman chess AI) just how plausible -- I can hardly wait.

Comment: Also a pretty decent book from a teen's point of view, when I read it last century.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - The novel was good. The sequels were dire

Comment: @releseabe The star is still working after fifty years — unlike the star of *A Deepness in the Sky*, har har

Comment: It also has a way of portraying the government's reaction to the events in a _far_ more credible way than today's over-dramatization of everything.

Comment: @pipe - [Shin-Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_Godzilla) was very much the same. What would the government *actually* do if a Kaiju turned up

Comment: In former SciFi (like from the 50ies) there was an emphasis on the idea, while today the emphasis seems to be on (visual) effects only. Ever tried to fly a starwar-like looping in space? The wings make the difference ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl et al: I think there's a bit of survivorship bias here - over-dramatic adventure fiction was *huge* in the 1950s, particularly in "pulp magazines" and "B-movies"; but generally those aren't the ones that are still famous 6 decades later.

Comment: I still enjoy thing like https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles